# binding list(of class) to datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

I have a class that contains a list of data that gets populated from a datastream. I want to bind that list to a datagridview so it automatically populates  as the list does. However the list isn't refreshing as the data comes in. I have something like this.

```
Public class MyClass
    Private mData as list(Of networkData)
    Public Property Data() as list(Of networkData)
        Get
            return mData
        End Get
        Set
            mData = value
        End Set
     End Property
        ' some other properties that aren't imporant
        ' stuff to load Data with data from network stream
end class
Public class networkDat
    Private rawdata as string
    Public Property rawdata() as string
        Get
            return mrawdata
        End Get
        Set
            mrawData = value
        End Set
     End Property
        ' some other properties that aren't imporant
        ' functions to parse rawdata into the other properties
End Class

'form
Public Class dataviewer
    Dim dataView as datagridViewer = new datagridviewer()
    Private Sub dataviewer_load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
         dim x as myClass = new myClass() 'new will start the datastream
         datagridview.datasource = x.Data
    End Sub
```

Since I started the datastream first dataviewer will have an inital set of data. However it doesn't update as new data comes in.

Comment: @LarsTech I updated my list to a binding list and it seems to be working. If you change your comment to an answer I can mark it as answered and give you credit for it. Now I just have to work out my threading issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The List class does not implement the IBindingList interface which supports list change notifications.

Try using the [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class instead:

> Provides a generic collection that supports data binding.

To observe changes to the properties in your class, the class would need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface:

> Notifies clients that a property value has changed.

Answer (score 0):

List(of ) does not support change notifications. For your purpose, change the List(of ) to a ObservableCollection(of ).